# Accessing __DATA__ from super class

Tags: perl, plack

I have a super class called Response :

```perl
package Response;

use strict;
use warnings;

use HTML::Template;

sub response {
    my ( $class, $request ) = @_;
    return $request->new_response( $class->status, $class->headers, $class->body );
}

sub body {
    my $class = shift;
    my $template = HTML::Template->new( 'filehandle' => eval("$class::DATA") );
    return $template->output() . $class;
}

sub status {
    return 200;
}

sub headers {
    return [ 'Content-Type' => 'text/html' ];
}

1;

__DATA__
Default content
```

and a subclass called URIError :

```perl
package URIError;

use strict;
use warnings;

use Response;
our @ISA = qw(Response);

1;

__DATA__
Invalid URI
```

When URIError->response is called, line

```perl
my $template = HTML::Template->new( 'filehandle' => eval("$class::DATA") );
```

in Response class does not takes **DATA** section content from URIError class.

What's the syntax to achieve this ?

Comment: This stinks. DATA can only be read once (unless you note the initial file position and seek back). Why not have an accessor that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code will work if you change the `body` method like this. There is no need for `eval`: all you have to do is disable `strict 'refs'` and dereference the string `"${class}::DATA"`

```
sub body {
   my $class = shift;

   my $data_fh = do {
      no strict 'refs';
      *{"${class}::DATA"};
   };

   my $template = HTML::Template->new( filehandle => $data_fh );

   $template->output . $class;
}
```

Comment: @user1474829 The preferred way of saying 'thanks' is by accepting the most helpful answer (click on the green checkmark) to any question you ask (which also increases a bit your reputation too), and by up-voting helpful answers (if you have 15+ reputation).  Please read the [tour], and good luck with the answers.

Comment: Sorry I never really went through all this marking process. Your answer is marked now ! Thanks again

Comment: @user1474829: Thank you; I'm pleased I could help you. (Note that the comment above yours wasn't from me but from @jm666)