# Difference between \*DATA and *DATA

Tags: perl

Whenever I want to simulate input and output to a filehandle, I'll often use references to `DATA` and `STDOUT` respectively:

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

#open my $infh, '<', 'infile.txt';
my $infh = \*DATA;

#open my $outfh, '>', 'outfile.txt';
my $outfh, \*STDOUT;

print $outfh <$infh>;

__DATA__
Hello World
```

Outputs:

```
Hello World
```

However, in a [recent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25710301/accessing-data-from-super-class/25711211#25711211) by Borodin, it was demonstrated that it's not actually necessary to take a reference.  Instead, a simple assignment is sufficient:

```
my $infh = *DATA;
```

I therefore created the following script to compare and contrast the difference between these two methods:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Fcntl qw(:seek);

# Compare Indirect Filehandle Notation
my %hash = (
    '\*DATA' => \*DATA,
    '*DATA'  => *DATA,
);

my $pos = tell DATA;

my $fmt = "%-8s %-22s %-7s %s\n";
printf $fmt, qw(Name Value ref() readline());

while ( my ( $name, $fh ) = each %hash ) {
    seek( $fh, $pos, SEEK_SET );    # Rewind FH
    chomp( my $line = <$fh> );
    printf $fmt, $name, $fh, ref($fh), $line;
}

__DATA__
Hello World
```

Outputs:

```
Name     Value                  ref()   readline()
\*DATA   GLOB(0x7fdc43027e70)   GLOB    Hello World
*DATA    *main::DATA                    Hello World
```

When it comes to passing and reading from the filehandle, there appears no difference between a typeglob and a reference to a typeglob.

Switching from testing to the research form of investigation reveals the following perldoc pages:

- [perldata - Typeglobs and Filehandles](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Typeglobs-and-Filehandles)
- [perlfaq5 - How can I use a filehandle indirectly?](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq5.html#How-can-I-use-a-filehandle-indirectly%3f)

The first reference suggests either usage.  While the second gives a list of other alternatives as well, but mentions how the reference notation is needed if we want to bless the variable.  No other difference is suggested.

Is there a functional or preferred style difference these two indirect filehandles?

1. `my $fh = \*DATA;`
2. `my $fh = *DATA;`

Comment: My immediate reaction is that every extra character adds that little bit extra potential for confusion somewhere down the road...

Comment: many places also accept an ioref (`*DATA{IO}`)

Comment: @abiessu, I'd say that being inconsistent with what `open my $fh` returns is actually more likely to cause confusion.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One's a glob; one's a reference to a glob. Most places accept both. Many also accept the name of the glob as a string, and many accept a reference to an IO object.

```
# Symbolic reference to the glob that contains the IO object.
>perl -E"$fh = 'STDOUT';    say $fh 'hi'"
hi

# Reference to the glob that contains the IO object.
>perl -E"$fh = \*STDOUT;    say $fh 'hi'"
hi

# Glob that contains the IO object.
>perl -E"$fh = *STDOUT;     say $fh 'hi'"
hi

# Reference to the IO object.
>perl -E"$fh = *STDOUT{IO}; say $fh 'hi'"
hi
```

`open(my $fh, '<', ...)` populates `$fh` with a reference to a glob, and it's the most supported, so that's what I use if I have to choose.

Comment: I'm glad to know there aren't any functional pitfalls to worry about with either.  Your last point about mirroring `open my $fh` is very useful from a style perspective.  Additionally, since most of the time I'm trying to model code for beginners, it's probably also useful to demonstrate using references since we don't to confuse them with an exception to the rule for how to pass complex data structures.